# Instagram oAuthException missing url

Tags: api, oauth, instagram

I am unable to make any /media/search calls to the Instagram api without getting errors.

In firefox, the endpoint

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&?access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

(Where VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN, is a valid access token that works successfully with other api calls.)

I get the following output

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthParameterException","code":400,"error_message":"\"client_id\" or \"access_token\" URL parameter missing. This OAuth request requires either a \"client_id\" or \"access_token\" URL parameter."}}
```

I can't make sense of this error, since clearly, the access token is present in the url.

Could it be some weird character encoding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick look at your URL and it looks like you have an extra `?` in there before the `access_token` parameter.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The first `?` tells it to accept parameters, and then each param is separated by &. You shouldn't need any more `?`'s and they may actually cause it to parse incorrectly.

Comment: Interesting... the url I posted before comes straight from Instagram's developer page [link](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search). Perhaps the ? in the example signifies "put more parameters here". Or it could be just a typo... Thanks for the answer.